# android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE not broadcasting when wifi get enabled and WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE not available

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, wifimanager

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".triggers.WifiTrigger">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

---

The receiver is executed when WiFi is disabled, connected or disconnected (didn't check for connecting/disabling/enabling) but it is not triggered when WiFi is enabled, in addition `WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE` extra is not available in the intent, i am using this :

```
public class WifiTrigger extends BroadcastReceiver {
    ...
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences preferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    int wifiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);
    int previousWifiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_WIFI_STATE, WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);
    log("p"+previousWifiState);
    log("c"+wifiState);
    //log is a defined method used for logging (it just calls Log.d(...,...)
    }
    ...
}
```

and it keeps logging `p4` `c4` (4 for WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN)

---

Comment: `is executed when wifi get enabled, connected or disconnected (didn't check for connecting/disabling/enabling) but it is not triggered when wifi is enabled` -- I'm assuming you meant "disabled" for one of these? Otherwise that's contradictory and it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: yes exactly, i just corrected it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're registering for the wrong Intent action. What you're really looking for is:

> ```
> /**
>  * Broadcast intent action indicating that Wi-Fi has been enabled, disabled,
>  * enabling, disabling, or unknown. One extra provides this state as an int.
>  * Another extra provides the previous state, if available.
>  *
>  * @see #EXTRA_WIFI_STATE
>  * @see #EXTRA_PREVIOUS_WIFI_STATE
>  */
> @SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.BROADCAST_INTENT_ACTION)
> public static final String WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION =
>     "android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED";
> ```

The action you're registering for is for network state changes, not adapter state changes:

> ```
> /**
>  * Broadcast intent action indicating that the state of Wi-Fi connectivity
>  * has changed. One extra provides the new state
>  * in the form of a {@link android.net.NetworkInfo} object. If the new
>  * state is CONNECTED, additional extras may provide the BSSID and WifiInfo of
>  * the access point.
>  * as a {@code String}.
>  * @see #EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO
>  * @see #EXTRA_BSSID
>  * @see #EXTRA_WIFI_INFO
>  */
> @SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.BROADCAST_INTENT_ACTION)
> public static final String NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION = 
>     "android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE";
> ```

So just changing your receiver registration from:

```
<receiver android:name=".triggers.WifiTrigger">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

to

```
<receiver android:name=".triggers.WifiTrigger">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

will fix your issue.